# Re-sharding a Cadence cluster: What is the latest version of cadence allows XDC replications when numHistoryShards are different?

Tags: cadence-workflow

I'm attempting to reshard my cadence cluster using the [provided guidance](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/operation-guide/maintain/#migrate-cadence-cluster)  by creating a new cluster with a number of higher number of shards and then enabling XDC .  What's the latest version of Cadence that isn't effected by the [*Allow CrossDC to replicate between clusters with different numbOfShards*](https://github.com/uber/cadence/issues/4179) bug?

Is there a way to determine if an existing domain is registered as a global domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>The bug is still open and we are working on it. I will come back to update this answer when we fix it.</s>

**The bug is [fixed](https://github.com/uber/cadence/pull/4239) and will be out in next release.**

To tell if a domain is a global domain, you can use CLI to describe the domain cluster lists( it may also be shown on the WebUI)

```
cadence --do samples-domain-global d desc
Name: samples-domain-global
UUID: 5ac45494-581f-4a86-890f-007bcab7feea
Description:
OwnerEmail:
DomainData: map[]
Status: REGISTERED
RetentionInDays: 3
EmitMetrics: true
ActiveClusterName: primary
Clusters: primary, secondary
```

However, if your global domain is only registered in one cluster, we recently improved it in this [issue](https://github.com/uber/cadence/issues/4228) to include a new field `IsGlobal(XDC)Domain`. The change is merged in master but not release yet. You can use docker run to use it:

1. update docker image via `docker pull ubercadence/cli:master`
2. Run the command

```
docker run --rm ubercadence/cli:master  --address  host.docker.internal:7933 --do samples-domain d desc
Name: samples-domain
UUID: ccd3fd09-b74b-41a6-8e2e-eff120e99772
Description:
OwnerEmail:
DomainData: map[]
Status: REGISTERED
RetentionInDays: 0
EmitMetrics: true
IsGlobal(XDC)Domain: false
ActiveClusterName: active
Clusters: N/A, Not a global domain
...
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Does the XDC feature for clusters with a different number of shards still work on Cadence 12.1 or was the bug introduced before that release?

Comment: It should work in theory in the earlier version like 12.1 which use Kafka for replication data delivery. However, we haven't tested that way, as our replication always set up with same number of shards so far. So I would recommend you to wait until we fix it.  When we fix it we will add test to make sure it works. 
 
I think you should just start a new cluster with larger shards, and create new global domain with one cluster.  If your domain is not global domain, it cannot be converted into a global one anyway. Next time you scale up again, hopefully we have fixed it.

Comment: Understood. This seems like the safest approach. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I added some notes about the naive approach to migrate a cluster like that: https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/operation-guide/maintain/#migrate-cadence-cluster LMK if you need more help

Comment: Updated the answer as we have fixed the issue to include a new field `IsGlobal(XDC)Domain` in CLI